# Adobe String Memory Leak - Where to Call External Library Entry Point to Free Memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, adobe, after-effects

I've created an After Effects script that extracts data from JSON files downloaded from an HTTPS URL. The problem is with the C++ DLL I've coded to download it and pass it back to the script. Even though it has been working fine, there was one instance of memory leak - After Effects issued a popup saying, "STRING MEMORY LEAK".

I'm new to C++ but I've managed to compose a DLL that downloads the files based on the examples provided with the After Effects installation (samplelib and basicexternalobject) as well as by Microsoft's C++ documentation. The Adobe JavaScript Tools Guide says that the method "ESFreeMem()" must be "called to free memory allocated for a null-terminated string passed to or from library functions". The problem is I don't know how or where to use it. I'm using After Effects CC 15.0.0 (build 180) on Windows 7.

This is the C++ function that gets some parameters from the javascript caller and returns a string with the JSON contents. If it fails it returns a bool (FALSE) so that the script can do what is necessary in this case.

```
extern "C" TvgAfx_Com_API long DownloadJson(TaggedData* argv, long argc, TaggedData * result)  
{  

     //... first I check the arguments passed  

// The returned value type  
result->type = kTypeString;  


//Converts from string into LPCWSTR ---------------------------------------------------  
std::wstring stemp = s2ws(argv[0].data.string);  
LPCWSTR jsonLink = stemp.c_str();  


std::wstring stemp02 = s2ws(argv[1].data.string);  
LPCWSTR jsonHeader = stemp02.c_str();  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  


//Class that does the HTTP request  
WinHttpClient client(jsonLink, jsonHeader);  


//Synchronous request   
if (client.SendHttpsRequest())  
{  
     string httpResponse = client.GetHttpResponse();  


     if (httpResponse.length() > 0)  
     {  
          //Sends response string back to javascript  
          result->data.string = getNewBuffer(httpResponse);  
     }  
     else  
     {  
           //Sends FALSE back to javascript  
           result->type = kTypeBool;  
           result->data.intval = 0;  
     }  
}  
else  
{  
     //Sends FALSE back to javascript  
     result->type = kTypeBool;  
     result->data.intval = 0;  
}  


return kESErrOK;  
}
```

The class WinHttpClient that does the actual request frees the memory allocated to the buffer that holds the response. Here's a piece of code:

```
// Read the data.  
ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);  

if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded))  
{  
//Log error  
}  
else  
{  
resource.append(pszOutBuffer).c_str();  
}  


// Free the memory allocated to the buffer.  
delete[] pszOutBuffer;
```

This is the function that the Adobe example uses to hold the string that will be returned to javascript:

```
//brief Utility function to handle strings and memory clean up  
static char* getNewBuffer(string& s)  
{  
// Dynamically allocate memory buffer to hold the string   
// to pass back to JavaScript  
char* buff = new char[1 + s.length()];  


memset(buff, 0, s.length() + 1);  
strcpy(buff, s.c_str());  


return buff;  
}
```

Now, the manual says this method must be implemented:

```
/** 
* \brief Free any string memory which has been returned as function result. 
* JavaScipt calls this function to release the memory associated with the string. 
* Used for the direct interface. 
* 
* \param *p Pointer to the string 
*/  
extern "C" SAMPLIB void ESFreeMem (void* p)  
{  
if (p)  
free (p);  
}
```

What I understand from this is that the memory associated with the json string returned must be released. But didn't the request class already do it? I just don't know where to call this method and what to pass on to it. I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a DLL ExternalObject for After Effects, it's really just an interface that you call via some ExtendScript script.  You have to load the ExternalObject in the AE Script and once loaded, the methods / functions you create in the C++ class can be called from the script.

You have to know [how to load the DLL in an ExtendScript script file](http://estk.aenhancers.com/7%20-%20Integrating%20External%20Libraries/loading-and-using-shared-libraries.html).  Then, you can call the methods of the DLL.